# KIE Workbench Test Scenarios as a part of Maven build

Tags: drools, kie-workbench, kie-wb, drools-kie-workbench

In my current project we need to run Test Scenarios created in Workbench as a part of a Maven build. The final goal is to have these functional tests included to the continuous integration process.

We spent a couple of days trying to figure it out. 
We opened a project that is created by Workbench in the `.niogit`folder and are trying to run a maven goal.

But seems that maven goals like `mvn clean install` or `mvn clean verify` or `mvn clean test` don't run the Test Scenarios having a `.scenario` type at all.

Do you have any ideas on that?

Answer (score 0):

Test scenarios are specific to kie-workbench. maven commands will not execute them during build. If you want tests to be executed during maven build then you have to write junit tests to check the execution of rules and processes.

Answer (score 0):

there is currently work in progress on new version of scenarios in the kie-workbench. See the [list of tasks](https://issues.jboss.org/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20DROOLS%20AND%20component%20%3D%20%22Scenario%20Simulation%20and%20Testing%22). I would recommend you to bring this requirement there.